# How do I use babel's `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` option on the vendors bundle?

Tags: internet-explorer, babeljs, polyfills, babel-polyfill

Since I need to support also IE11, I need to transpile also `node_modules`.

This is the babel config I use on the node_modules:

```
presets: [
  ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false, useBuiltIns: 'usage' }],
],
```

I use the `useBuiltIns` options because it was giving an error `Symbol is not defined`, the polyfill was needed.

However this configuration breaks at compile time, supposedly because it injects some `imports` in the code, here is the error:

[image: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>']

Basically it's not liking the `module.exports`. So how do I use `useBuiltIns` in the vendors bundle?

For now I solved by always requiring the babel polyfill in the `index.html`, however this is not ideal.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Babel by default assumes that files it processes are ES modules (using `import` and `export`). If you are running Babel on things in `node_modules` (which are likely CommonJS modules), you'll need to either tell Babel to process all `node_modules` as scripts, or tell Babel to guess the type based on the presence of `import` and `export`. Guessing is easiest, so you can add

```yaml
sourceType: "unambiguous"
```

and also tell Babel not to run the `usage` transform on `core-js` itself with

```yaml
ignore: [
  /\/core-js/,
],
```

because otherwise the `usage` transform will actually be inserting references to `core-js` into *itself* causing dependency cycles.

So in your top-level Babel configuration, you'd do e.g.

```yaml
{
  ignore: [
    /\/core-js/,
  ],
  sourceType: "unambiguous",
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false, useBuiltIns: 'usage' }],
  ],
}
```

If you wanted to be extra specific about it, you could also do

```yaml
{
  ignore: [
    /\/core-js/,
  ],
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false, useBuiltIns: 'usage' }],
  ],
  overrides: [{
    test: "./node_modules",
    sourceType: "unambiguous",
  }],
}
```

to only set the flag for files inside `node_modules`, but there is likely not much to gain by doing that.

As for *why* this fixes that error, the issue is that, if Babel thinks something is an ES module, it will insert `import` statements. If you insert `import` statements into a file that also uses CommonJS things like `module.exports`, it means the file would now be using both module systems in the same file, which is a big issue and causes the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Tried this, this error came up: https://i.imgur.com/slZtKT5.png which is a progress because it's a different error!

Comment: by the way, it should be noted that in this case I am passing the babel config as options to the [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)

Comment: @Pontiacks I've added another `excludes` to the config, if you want to give that a shot.

Comment: `/@babel\b/` should also be excluded, at least when `transform-runtime` is used