# Webpack and Babel not transpiling a dependency inside node_modules that breaks IE 11 and Edge due to ES6's spread syntax

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader, es6-modules

I have a project that uses `@mdx-js/runtime` and it completely breaks on IE 11 or Edge (`Edge 44.18362.449.0`):

```
SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
```

It actually breaks because of the spread syntax here:

```
const allNodes = sortedNodes.map(({ start: _, ...node }, i) => {
```

This line of code comes from `remark-mdx`, which is a dependency of `@mdx-js/runtime`, particularly this file and line: https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/blob/master/packages/remark-mdx/extract-imports-and-exports.js#L66

I've been trying to get Webpack and Babel to transform that file so that the spread is no longer there:

**Browserlist:**

If I run `npx browserslist` I can see IE 11 is there.

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 0.5%",
    "last 2 version",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "not dead",
    "iOS >= 9"
]
```

**.babelrc:**

I've tried disabling `loose` mode and adding `@babel/plugin-transform-spread` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`, but didn't fix the issue.

```
  {
    "presets": [[
        "@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "loose": false, // Was true before
            "modules": "auto",
            "corejs": 3
        }],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],

    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {
            "legacy": true
        }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {
            "loose": true
        }],
        "@babel/plugin-transform-spread", // Just added
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread", // Just added
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ]
}
```

**`webpack.config.js:`**

Here I tried explicitly including `remark-mdx` and `@mdx-js/runtime` and also removing the `exclude` property or changing it to `/node_modules\/(?!(remark-mdx|@mdx-js\/runtime)\/).*/`, but nothing seems to work:

```
  {
    test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      // Tried explicitly adding these 2:
      path.resolve('node_modules/remark-mdx'),
      path.resolve('node_modules/@mdx-js/runtime'),
    ],
    // Tried removing `exclude` or not excluding those 2 packages:
    // exclude: /node_modules/,
    // exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(remark-mdx|@mdx-js\/runtime)\/).*/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        babelrc: true,
      }
    }],
  }
```

I'm using Babel 7 an Webpack 4.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question in the Discussion of Babel? https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/16228. Thank you for this awesome Q&A btw!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, it turns out to process files inside `node_modules` you need to use `babel.config.js` rather than `.babelrc` as explained [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) and [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading):

> **What's your use case?**
>
> - You are using a monorepo?
> - You want to compile node_modules?
>
>   `babel.config.json` is for you!
> - You have a configuration that only applies to a single part of your project?
>
>   `.babelrc.json` is for you!

Also, if you are using a monorepo you need to set [`rootMode: 'upward'`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#rootmode) so that Babel can find your new config file, as explained [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos).

Webpack's `babel-loader` config should look something like this:

```
  {
    test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      // No need to add @mdx-js/runtime, just add the problematic package:
      path.resolve('node_modules/remark-mdx'),
    ],
    // You also need to exclude it from the exclusions:
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(remark-mdx)\/).*/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        // And replace .babelrc with babel.config.json...
        babelrc: false,
        // ...which might also mean you need this if you are using a monorepo:
        rootMode: 'upward',
      }
    }],
  }
```

After this change the file was being processed, but I was getting a different error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

In this case, I had to add [`sourceType: "unambiguous"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype) to `babel.config.json`, as `remark-mdx` was using CommonJS modules rather than ES6 ones. You can add this at the root of your `babel.config.json` file or inside [`overrides`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#overrides), so that it only targets packages inside `node_modules`.

For more on why this happens, see [How do I use babel's `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` option on the vendors bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407499/how-do-i-use-babels-usebuiltins-usage-option-on-the-vendors-bundle).

Babel's `babel.config.json` ended up looking like this:

```
{
    "presets": [[
        "@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "usage",
            "loose": true,
            "modules": "auto",
            "corejs": 3
        }],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],

    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {
            "legacy": true
        }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {
            "loose": true
        }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ],

    "overrides": [{
        "test": "./node_modules",
        "sourceType": "unambiguous"
    }]
}
```