# Transform of Swiper v4 for IE11 failed (with Webpack 5 + Babel 7)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, swiper.js, babel-loader

I build and pushed a simplified version of what I'd like to do:
https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7

### What it should do

When open the [index.html](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/index.html) in Internet Explorer 11 (IE11), the slideshow with [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com) is working.

### What happend

The IE11 throws the error:

```
SCRRIPT1002: Syntax error
vendors.js (3135,1)
```

This is caused by a `class` declaration in [line 3135](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/dist/js/vendors.js#L3135).

---

I have to use [Swiper v4](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/tree/Swiper4), since it's the last compatible version for IE11.

The current setup of [Webpack 5](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/gulpfile.esm.js#L35-L44) uses [Babel 7](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/.babelrc) and the [Browserlist](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/.browserslistrc) from Bootstrap.

The debug of babel shows:

```
...

Using targets:
{
  "android": "4.4",
  "chrome": "45",
  "edge": "12",
  "firefox": "38",
  "ie": "10",
  "ios": "9",
  "opera": "30",
  "safari": "9",
  "samsung": "12"
}

...

Using plugins:
...
transform-classes { "android":"4.4", "chrome":"45", "edge":"12", "firefox":"38", "ie":"10", "ios":"9", "opera":"30", "safari":"9" }
...
```

You can see that the transformation for classes is running, when look into the result of [example class](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/source/Slider.mjs#L9) in:
https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/master/dist/js/source_Slider_mjs.239afbde125d3f32e9af.js#L18

BUT it didn't transform the mentions `class Dom7` from [node_modules/dom7/dist/dom7.modular.js](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/426cbdedd6b7d55ab606066fafa0b0fd9a47d027/node_modules/dom7/dist/dom7.modular.js#L16).

---

Currently I have no clue why it doesn't work.

From my point of view I would expect that `babel-loader` will transform all the code *including* files from `node_modules`.

I really hope someone has a hint for me and point me into the right direction. Please.

---

## EDIT 1

After renameíng `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` and adding a [little configuration](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/da2e1ea27d6cfbaaeea8c2d4b75ac2a36a04da8c/gulpfile.esm.js#L41-L43) to `babel-loader`, the code of `class Dom7` is transformed correctly.

**BUT**, now I face the issue within every browser with the error:

> ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead: WA63

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack and Babel not transpiling a dependency inside node_modules that breaks IE 11 and Edge due to ES6's spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395262/webpack-and-babel-not-transpiling-a-dependency-inside-node-modules-that-breaks-i)

Comment: Thanks you for your response. It helped a little, but it produce the following error described in EDIT 1.

Comment: I found the issue and will post it as anwer. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version:
https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7

The keychanges:

- rename `.babelrc` into [babel.config.json](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/master/babel.config.json)
- update the options for `babel-loader` within the [Webpack config](https://github.com/vaxul/swiper4-webpack5-babel7/blob/master/gulpfile.esm.js#L41-L46)

  - set `babelrc: false`
  - exclude `core-js` and `webpack/buildin` form transformation, [like described here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#exclude-libraries-that-should-not-be-transpiled)